# ContenTypes on List Definition not added

Tags: 2010, content-type, list-definition, feature-receiver

I've an ListDefinition with some references to existing Content Types (provided by CTH) but when the list is created the content types are not added.

elements.xml

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <ListTemplate
        Name="MyDocLib"
        Type="10081"
        BaseType="1"
        OnQuickLaunch="FALSE"
        SecurityBits="11"
        Sequence="110"
        DisplayName="My Document Library"
        Description="My Document Library List Definition"
        Image="/_layouts/images/itdl.png"
        DocumentTemplate="100"
        DisallowContentTypes="FALSE"/>
</Elements>
```

schema.xml

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="My Document Library" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="ProjectName-MyDocLib" BaseType="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <MetaData>
        <ContentTypes>
            <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0101001239678203837B4FBA21976C8B194FFD02" />
            <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0101001239678203837B4FBA21976C8B194FFD03" />
    </ContentTypes>
    (...)
```

web feature creation receiver code:

```
oWeb.Lists.Add(oWeb.Name, "my doc lib description", oWeb.Name, "featureWhereIsListDefID", 10081, "100", SPListTemplate.QuickLaunchOptions.Off);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the dark side of SharePoint.

To be simple, that does not works (nearly never). When you create a list, duplicate the whole content types and the fields definition within your list.

Yes, you have to copy paste the whole content each time you change an attribute in a field or in a content type.

You can use VS 2012 RC which can help you a bit (a small trick I can explain if needed), but you'll still end in duplicating things.

I just wish someone will write a small extension that will do this work automatically.

Comment: hahaha! thanks a lot Steve. Dark side indeed, I went for this approach cause I've around 30 CTypes to add, and programmatically takes an eternity (almost 1s foreach oSPList.ContentTypes.Add()). Can you suggest and better approach for this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not. As I said, VS 2012 has new list schema designer, that helps to duplicate the mess. This can help a bit. Another idea, is to create a site, design it using the UI, and export it as a template. A final idea, is to write a Visuaal Studio addin that do the job, or a T4 template, or anything. OF course this assume you are living in the Vault 13, and that you nothing to do of your Saturday.

Comment: hahahaha! Vault 13, u r old school. To bad that I cannot embrace that approach, or others that obligate to duplicate the content types. The idea is to stick into the CTH purpose. However, thanks a lot!!!